# Windows 7 "send to compressed (zip) folder" omits some folders whose name begins with a dot

Tags: windows-7

I have this directory structure:

```
EclipseWorkspace
---.metadata
------.mylyn
------.plugins
```

When using a "Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder" function on a EclipseWorkspace directory, the resulting archive doesn't include the .plugins directory! No error message is given, the operation completes as if it was successful - the zip archive is just incomplete.

Does anyone have any ideas how to prevent it (without changing the directory structure)?

Comment: Can you manually drag them into the archive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Windows Explorer does not allow the creation of folders whose names begin with a period (although the underlying file system obviously can handle them just fine), guess Compressed Folders doesn't deal with them too well either. As per my quick tests it seems to add only the *first* folder that begins with a period, skipping the rest.

Since the "feature" has such major deficiencies (it [doesn't even support Unicode](https://superuser.com/a/481366/138343) in this day and age), I highly recommend you use a proper archiver instead.

Comment: Since it obviously can't be trusted (It doesn't even report an error! I'm feeling sorry for people who archived their data  only to find some folders missing afterwards...), I'm switching to 7-Zip. It provides essentially the same context menu functionality, only working properly (at least for my case).