# What compressed archive formats can Windows 8 open natively?

Tags: windows-8, archiving

I like Windows' built-in handling of ZIP files, and I like to associate compressed files with Windows Explorer whenever possible, rather than a third-party file archiver like 7-zip. Aside from ZIP and ISO, what other formats can Windows 8 open natively?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1677299/what-types-of-compressed-archives-does-microsoft-windows-understand-by-default

Answer (score 2):

Other than CAB and ZIP which have been supported for ages, none I can think of (ISO isn't a *compressed* archive format, although native mounting support for it and VHD *is* [new to Win8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/30/accessing-data-in-iso-and-vhd-files.aspx)).

BTW, I wouldn't be so quick to place my faith in the **Compressed Folders** feature. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/481366/138343) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/566207/138343) for more. 7-Zip is free or you can try commercial archivers such as WinRAR or WinZip – any of them is *far* better than what's included with Windows (actually, it's not even a contest). The *only* time I use the in-built feature is when I'm on a fresh OS install and absolutely desperate due to lack of access to one of the alternatives.