# Archive file-format without Zip's invalid-character limitation

Tags: windows, filesystems, zip, archiving

Zip files can't contain files with names with certain characters. I haven't even been able to find an official list or rule for these.

What file type can I use to archive a folder's content into a file, where there will be no limit on the characters allowed; That if it's OK for Windows it's OK for that file?

Comment: Could you give an example of such a character? What program are you using to create the zip?

Comment: @Seth Using Windows Explorer. See https://superuser.com/questions/476740/error-while-zipping-files-with-unicode-characters-in-names-with-win7s-send-to

Comment: As the answer to that question details, it's probably a limit of the Windows zip implementation. Did you try to use a third party software like 7-Zip, WinRAR, WinZip or similar to create a zip with an "offending" file? At least for me it works with WinRAR and 7-Zip.